# How to capture text value of parent element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to capture the text value of a parent class when a click event happens . In this case the parent class ame is mb-name and will have a "text value" associated with it. I want to capture that text. below is the html.

```
<div class="mbs-item-inner">
   <div class="mb-img">,,,</div>
   <h5 class="mb-name">Joe Banker</p>
   <p class="mb-title">Banker</h5>
   <p class="mb-loc">Virginia Beach, VA</p>
   <p class="mb-view">
     <a href = "......." class= "btn-ghost-blue" target="_blank">VIEW ME</a> ==          $0
</p>
```

the click event happens on the class = mb-view.. I want to capture the class = mb name "in this case Joe Banker". I tried the following

```
document.getElementByClassName("mb-name").text;
return true;
```

and a few other variants of `document.getElementssbyClassName` but nothing works. I welcome all suggestions.

Comment: My question is nothing like the question suggested as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

This piece of code should do what you want.

```
    document.getElementsByClassName('mb-name')[0].innerHTML;
```

I'd advise you to clean up your HTML a bit. You're starting a h5-tag which ends with a p-tag and vice versa.

Had you been using jquery you could to the same like this:

```
    $('h5.mb-name').text();
```

Comment: The HTl was a rush , but its just fine on the site, I am not the coder for the site. I just try to hurry and type what element I was concerned with, not paying attention to syntax etc.. I will try your suggestion. Thank you for your response

Comment: so i did the following..   var name = document.getElementsByClassName('mb-name')[0].innerHTML; return name;  .... The problem is, that it is bubbling up and grabbing the mb-name from the very first Element in the list. In other words the html code I post above represents just one of many of the same in a list.. so instead of grabbing the mb-name associated with the actual click event it bubbles up to the top of the list and grabs the very first mb-name.. How do I get around this?

Comment: Then you'll need to make sure that the click-event is set up for its own parent object. Like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tLyy0e2/3/)